# Testing WCF Service that Uses Impersonation

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, nunit, impersonation

I am converting some existing integration tests of a legacy WCF service to be automated via NUnit.  The current tests call a deployed version of the WCF service; what I would like to do is have the tests hit the service class (MyService.svc.cs) directly/internally.

The problem I am having is that the service uses impersonation:

```
    //this is a method in MyService.svc.cs
    public SomeObject GetSomeObject()
    {
      using (GetWindowsIdentity().Impersonate())
      {
        //do some stuff
      }

      return null;
    }

    private WindowsIdentity GetWindowsIdentity()
      {
        var callerWinIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;

        var cf = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>();
        cf.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        return callerWinIdentity;
    }
```

The problem is that ServiceSecurityContext.Current is always null when I call it from a unit test.

The impersonation is important in downstream operations, so I can't just bypass this code and just call what is within the `using` block.  It might be possible to wrap my test code in `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()` and *then* call what is within the `using` block (bypassing MyService.svc.cs code), but this would be less than ideal, as it would not be a complete end-to-end test.

I do not need to fake different users to impersonate--I just need the runner's user context to be available in ServiceSecurityContext.Current.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still be interested in a better and less invasive way of doing this, but this seems to work for now.

I created a second constructor for MyService to allow the use of `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.

```
    private readonly bool _useLocalIdentity;

    public MyService(bool useLocalIdentity) :this()
    {
        _useLocalIdentity = useLocalIdentity;
    }


    private WindowsIdentity GetWindowsIdentity()
      {
        if (_useLocalIdentity)
        {
            return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        }

        var callerWinIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
        if (callerWinIdentity == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Caller not authenticated");
        }

        var cf = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>();
        cf.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        return callerWinIdentity;
    }
```